# Vertex Paint on faceless model

Tags: vertex-colors

Is it possible to apply vertex colors to vertices that aren't part of a face?

I've tried using vertex paint mode in the Blender application, and also directly modifying a vertex paint object via python, neither or which worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [wiki](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Materials/Special_Effects/Vertex_Paint)
says:

> The color of all visible planes and edges attached to the vertex are
>   then modified with a gradient to the color of the other connected
>   vertices. (Note that the color of non-visible faces are not modified).

As I understand this, it works on gradients which are not available without edges and faces. Thus you can't paint isolated vertices.

Comment: I don't care about visualization though; I just want to attach values to vertices

Comment: @ajwood I already wondered what you're actually trying to achieve, you also can't add custom-properties to vertices , check the last post by codemanx here: http://blenderartists.org/forum/archive/index.php/t-313260.html I wouldn't have expected such. An alternative that always works in scripts is a mapping: vertex-id to custom-data.

Comment: I'm doing some scientific visualization.. I've got a few thousand edges/curves, each with a value which will determine their colour. I can either add them as separate objects (color based on a whole-object property) or as one big object (color based on _______)

Comment: I'm trying to figure out which answer to accept for http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/12143/rendering-unconnected-edges