# Export vertex colors in a mesh with no faces?

Tags: export, vertices, obj, vertex-paint-mode

Basically, what I'm trying to do is export some kind of custom per-vertex data from blender.

The closest thing I've found is: according to [this post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31997/how-can-i-get-vertex-painted-obj-files-to-import-into-blender), blender can extend the .obj format to include vertex colors, which I would find very useful, except for the fact that it only seems to do this on meshes with faces.

I have a series of 3D points in blender (a connected line), and I want to be able to "tag" them so that when I parse the exported file I can know which one of them is the "start" and which is the "end," as blender doesn't export vertices in any particular order. I wouldn't use the vertex color values as actual colors, if that makes any sense.

Any suggestions? I'm trying to make a 3D game.
Thank you.

edit: basically the same question as

[Vertex Paint on faceless model](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/12180/vertex-paint-on-faceless-model)

https://www.reddit.com/r/blender/comments/teg5y6/how_do_i_add_custom_vertex_data_to_a_model/

Comment: The new (non-legacy) OBJ exporter exports vertex colors since Blender 3.3 (check "Geometry > Colors" when you export). Exporting without faces works fine here. Be aware if you're not using them for real colors that they're exported in sRGB space.

Comment: On a tangential note, if you're making a game, I recommend writing your own exporter. It's not very hard and it'll be much easier than trying to get the default ones to do exactly what you want.

Comment: @scurest thanks for the reply! I'll look into making a custom exporter. I have a follow up question though, it seems like the vertex paint mode in blender itself doesn't want to let me paint on a mesh with no faces. When a mesh with faces is selected, there's the circular cursor with the adjustable radius that you use for drawing, but when you select a mesh with no faces, it disappears.

Comment: AFAIK there's no way to paint vertex colors without faces. I tested it by setting it with a script.