# Colouring hair with vertex paint

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, particles, vertex-colors

Is it possible to get a vertex paint layer into a cycles hair material, when the hairs are emitted from vertices?

Here is a vertex paint layer working for the emitter, but the hair strands don't get the info:
[image]

Note that interpolated children strands *do* pick up the vertex paint info. This is also true for hair emitted from faces. These don't work for me, because I need the hair to be emitted from the vertices:

[image]

(I'm still trying to get [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/12143/822) question working)

Comment: I'm sure this is a bug.  Notice how the hairs are black at the corners?  When I baked the vertex colors to a texture and then use that instead of the Attribute node, the black clears up and the hairs end up with default white-ish grey(but still not the texture color).  Remove that node and adjust the color directly and it's all fine.  The Diffuse node seems to be accepting input in a way that breaks for hair depending on the input type.  So far as I understand it, the Shader node should have no concept of different types of color input.  It should see them all as being exactly the same type.

Comment: I've filed a bug report.  https://developer.blender.org/T42706?workflow=create

Comment: Thanks! I don't quite understand everything in your first comment; is there a way to workaround the bug with baking? If so, can you make that into an answer?

Comment: It was my intention to find and post a workaround but unfortunately baking the texture didn't work for this, it just seems like the shader fails less miserably.