# How to assign a specific weight to vertices? (instead of painting it)

Tags: vertices, weight-painting

I was wondering that in the weight painting mode, how can I set a specific weight for a certain group of vertices instead of painting it over them?

Comment: You could use python to do this. What do you intend to use the weight for?

Comment: @ajwood, not sure what is the purpose of suggesting Python for this task.

Comment: @ideasman42, for visualizing scientific data, I often script _vertex painting_. I haven't come across a situation where I need to do the same with _weight painting_, but I bet it'll come up sooner or later.

Comment: @ideasman42, I've actually been wondering if weight painting can help me get around [this bug](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/19159/822) to let me put hair over a huge mesh, with colors specified per-vertex.. will definitely need Python for that.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Ah, I was fooling around and found an answer.

- In the **weight painting mode**, use the **Vertex selection masking for painting**  <kbd>V</kbd>
- Select wanted vertices **for example with Circle select tool** <kbd>C</kbd>
- Set the wanted **weight** from **Tool Shelf** <kbd>T</kbd>
- Weights -> **Set Weight** <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>

[image]

In addition, there's a useful addon for setting weight values:
http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Paint/Palettes

Comment: Nice! Very useful method I haven't heard of before.

Comment: You my friend are a hero! :) This answer never gets old - I just found it and it solved a headache I've been struggling with all day in Blender 3.4.1!

Answer (score 19):

In *'Edit Mode'* assign the desired vertex group and change their weight in *'Vertex Groups'* panel.[image]
Enter the *'Weight Paint Mode'* to see the result.
[image]

Comment: Awesome, thanks!
I can see a lot of uses for this method as well :D

Comment: I usually start off like this so I can select the portion of mesh using L and then apply a base weight. Its a good way to get in all the little nooks and crannies.

Comment: In Blender 2.79 at least, the role of the Assign button is to include the selected vertices in the group, if the they weren't already included in it, and to assign them the current value of the Weight selector. So to assign a weight to one or more given vertices in Edit mode or Weight Paint, the order of operations is rather 1/ Select a weight with the cursor, 2/ Select the vertices, 3/ Click Assign.