# Animating parts of an object

Tags: animation, rigging, bones

[image: Radar]
Hi is it possible to rotate part of a mesh but without any stretching (I understand weight painting a little) For instance I want to be able to animate just the radar dish around the z axis. Is this doable and is there a fast way such as through a vertex group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two (of many) ways to do it:

Select the radar in edit mode and press P to have it separated in a new object, and animate the whole object, without even the need of an armature.

Or

Create an armature which has a "Radar" bone, parent (Ctrl P) the mesh to the armature and choose "with empty groups" option, then in edit mode select all vertices of the radar, select in the properties panel the newly created "Radar" vertex group and click the "assign" button.

Comment: Hi josh thanks for the help. I know how to seperate the object but I want a single object so it's option 2. I am little stuck. I have the radar and I have edited it  and created a vertex group called radardish with just the dish highlighted in orange above. Then I added an armature and CTRL P using with empty groups. Now I am a little unclear do I go into edit mode in the bone or the radar? Many thanks

Comment: Select the mesh, go to edit mode and select the radardish. In the properties window you will find the vertex group tab with a newly created empty group named radardish (as you named its relative bone). Click the assign weight button and you're done. (Related, 2.79, but 2.81 is the same https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19450/how-to-assign-a-specific-weight-to-vertices-instead-of-painting-it).

Comment: Hi all just to update thanks for help. Yes it works exactly as I wanted. My mistake was not animating the bone in pose mode.