# Specific Weight to Vertex Group

Tags: vertex-groups, vertex-weights

I'm still trying to understand the concept of vertex groups, so any help would be appreciated. I'm currently trying to follow [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hGWXtnRf1XI) to create a "trampoline", but I'm stuck trying to assign weights to different vertexes.
[image: screen]

Here I've got the inside vertices selected (and set as a vertex group) which is going to be the "cloth" part, whose weight I want to set at 0, but I want the rest of the cube's weight to be set at 1.

For some reason whenever I try to set it to a different weight (by weight painting it or by creating a different vertex group), one of the weight settings reset (so either the vertex group somehow changes to select every vertex on the cube or the whole cube's weight is set to 0).

I've tried looking at [this previous question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19450/how-to-assign-a-specific-weight-to-vertices-instead-of-painting-it) for reference but I couldn't seem to set the weight of the selected verticies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Invert your selection and assign that to the vertex group. By nature, vertexes with zero weight are either in the vertex group for a weird reason, or not in it at all. You cannot say “be not in this group with a weight of one.” The vertex group you’re creating should be for the “pins” AKA the still parts of the trampoline, rather than to assign the cloth. It is set up this way since the cloth simulation will of course assume everything is cloth. The vertex group is telling it what isn’t.